# Which parts of the Windows API are not accessible from ANSI C code?

Tags: c, winapi, ansi-c

Before 2000, I have been using ANSI C for Windows programming. Later I changed to C++ and MFC, then to Delphi, and nowadays I prefer C#, but I'm curious if it is still possible to use plain C to access every API of the modern editions of Windows.

For example, [even COM/OLE objects can be dealt with from C](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C).

Comment: Considering the Windows true *api* is C to begin with (and still is), I'd go with **yes**. Everything else is just layered on top of it (for the most part).

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you. This is what I would expect, but is there any official claim from Microsoft about whether they will keep C APIs in the future?

Comment: Look up "GDI+" for a counterexample.

Comment: Official? Not that I've ever seen, but I wouldn't hold my breath for it. I suppose every time they publish a Windows SDK it reaffirms it, and since they're continue to pile into it, I'd say its a long shot it will ever go away (at least in our lifetimes). I assure you the wrath of the divine will reign fire and brimstone upon them if they *ever* ever considered the idea, even in passing. There is literally *billions* of lines of code that require it, and making all that obsolete would make for an even quicker path to Linux/Mac then they're already hemorrhaging.

Comment: @librik GDI+ has a so-called "flat API", which is accessible from ANSI C. However, MSDN says "Microsoft Product Support Services will not provide support for code that calls the flat API directly." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533969(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @WhozCraig Why don't you add your comments as an answer?

Comment: Because I didn't actually provide an answer, only an opinion. You wanted to know specifics that I can only speculate on. Given it is highly probable speculation, but still just opinion in the end. Lior's answer is pretty solid, citing both API definition, and some examples of exceptions. If it were me, I'd up-vote him (and did, in fact =P)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows APIs list is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Most of the APIs are C-based (structures and functions). However, few are C++ based (classes):

- [COM+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [XAudio2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Volume Shadow Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Network Diagnostics Framework (NDF) extensible helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [DirectXMath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/directxmath-portal)

Comment: +1, and noted: All of these is still accessible from C (and if you've never programmed COM interfaces in C, you don't know what you're missing).

Comment: I agree with @WhozCraig. "C++ based" means only that there are classes, but the vtable (the lpVtbl member of COM classes) is still accessible from C. Sometimes there is a C version of the API too, like the "flat API" in case of GDI+. What I would like to know is whether there is an API to which there is *absolutely* no C access.